# Posting Feeds to Facebook using Graph API - Server side

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to post feeds to the personal facebook wall and the fan page wall from my site for a logged in user.

```
<cfhttp url="https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed" method="post">
    <cfhttpparam name="access_token" value="#variables.accessToken#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="message" value="#arguments.message#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="link" value="#arguments.link#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="name" value="#arguments.name#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="caption" value="#arguments.caption#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="description" value="#arguments.description#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="picture" value="#arguments.picturePath#" type="formfield">
</cfhttp>
```

This is as per the code from developers.facebook.com and a sample from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/wrangling-with-the-facebook-graph-api/

**This is just a sample of what I think the parameters mean:**

[image]

But when it posts to the wall, the following happens:

- The message, picture, name, caption and description appear properly
- But the link does not, the picture points to itself and the link on the name points to the picture.

After referring to numerous posts, I thought I'd post this.

Please help.

Comment: Please add the results of linting the url being posted. Linter here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint

Comment: This is the URL I'm providing in the link option: http://www.traffikworks.com/community.html

Comment: You should give the protocol as well. So try this: http:// www.traffikworks.com/community.html (I put the www, becuase as I see you redirect the browser anyway with 301)

Answer (score 0):

You should give the protocol as well.

So try this: 
http://www.traffikworks.com/community.html

(I put the www, becuase you redirect the browser anyway with 301)

Comment: I did that, still doesn't work. The problem is the link on the image and the name point to the image not the link that I set.

Comment: I think it's happening if your url is not working, or may be something overwrite the link param somewhere. I just suggest to put few line code to your server to stores the POST request fields in a file. Call that script instead of https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed , and you will see what's the problem. If the POST snapshot contains the same url what you tried to post, you will know that your code works.